# google cloud storage failed to read file

Tags: eclipse, google-cloud-storage

Using the example from google, this is the way I am trying to read my file:

```
boolean lockForRead = false;
String filename = "/gs/my_bucket/my_object";
AppEngineFile readableFile = new AppEngineFile(filename);
FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(readableFile, lockForRead);

// Read the file in whichever way you'd like
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF8"));
String line = reader.readLine();
resp.getWriter().println("READ:" + line);

readChannel.close();
```

However, the code seams fine up to the reader.readLine line, where it throws an exception:

```
java.io.IOException
    at com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceImpl.translateException(FileServiceImpl.java:615)
```

....

```
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 7: ...\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\encoded_gs_key:L2dzL21hcGxlL3NhdmUudHh0 (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Help!

Comment: It looks like this was asked in 2013; is this still an issue or have you resolved it since then?